# How to import hadoop files into intellJ?

Tags: java, hadoop, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I haven't used Java in a long time so forgive me:

I downloaded mapreduce to run on a single, local node on my computer, and I'm following [apache's tutorial](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html) on running WordCount. The problem is that when I try to compile my WordCount.java file, the compiler can't find the imports required at the top of the class:

```
package org.hadoopExamples;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

public class WordCount {

// ....
```

Where can I find these files and where do I put them? I can't find them in the Hadoop download I'm using (version 1.2.1).

Answer (score 0):

Download 'hadoop-core.jar', 'hadoop-common.jar' and 'hadoop-mapreduce-client-core.jar' and add to your dependencies.

Go to project- properties - java build path- libraries. 
Click external jars and upload these 2 and apply

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/1.2.1
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/2.2.0
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/0.23.1